If $x^{**}\otimes y^*$ is an extreme point of the unit ball of $K(X, Y)^*$, does it imply that $x^{**}\in S_{X^{**}}$ and $y^*\in S_{Y^*}$?
I am studying an interesting work $\textbf{Extreme points in duals of complex operator spaces}$ of $\textbf{A. Lima and G. Olsen}$ which is published in 1985. There I have faced some difficulty with the proof of the main result (p.439 Theorem $1$). Here it is:
Let $X$ and $Y$ be complex Banach spaces. $X^*$ is the dual space of $X$. Denote $B_X=\{x\in X:\|x\|\leq 1\}$, $S_X=\{x\in X:\|x\|=1\}$ and $ext(B_X)$ is the set of all extreme points of $B_X$. $K(X, Y)$ denotes the space of all compact operators from $X$ to $Y$. At the beginning of the proof in page $439$ they have taken $x_0^{**}\in ext(B_{X^{**}})$ and $y_0^*\in ext(B_{Y^*})$ and $h^*=x_0^{**}\otimes y_0^*\in K(X, Y)^*$. Then they have shown that $h^*$ is an extreme point of $B_{K(X, Y)^*}$. Here, the action of the tensor product is as follows:
$$x^{**}\otimes y^*:K(X, Y)\to\mathbb{C}~\text{such that}~[x^{**}\otimes y^*] (T)=x^{**}(T^*y^*).$$
Now, my question is how to show $\|h^*\|=1$? I am not able to understand from the proof. Is it trivial that for $x^{**}\in ext(B_{X^{**}})$ and $y^*\in ext(B_{Y^*})$, $\|x^{**}\otimes y^*\|=1$? How to conclude this?
On the other hand, if $x^{**}\otimes y^*\in ext(B_{K(X, Y)^*})$ then $x^{**}\in S_{X^{**}}$ and $y^*\in S_{Y^*}$. Is this also trivial or how to conclude it?
I am totally helpless. Any kind of help is appreciated. Please help me. Thank you in advance.

Any extreme point of a unit ball has norm $1$.

@DavidGao Thank you for your comment. But showing extreme point is much more stronger than showing its norm one. I stuck in showing its norm one. If you go through the proof you will see before proving that one an extreme point they somehow used its norm is one.

Ah, no, that’s not what I meant. I meant $x^{\ast\ast}$ and $y^\ast$ are extreme points, so they have norm $1$, so $x^{\ast\ast} \otimes y^\ast$ has norm $1$. Also for the converse, assuming $x^{\ast\ast}$ and $y^\ast$ are in the unit ball, then as $x^{\ast\ast} \otimes y^\ast$ is an extreme point, it has norm $1$, so $x^{\ast\ast}$ and $y^\ast$ must have norm $1$ as well.

Now that I looked at this more, is your main question actually about how to show $|x^{\ast\ast} \otimes y^\ast| = |x^{\ast\ast}||y^\ast|$? If so, I can write an answer showing that.

@DavidGao Yes exactly this one I want to know. This was my query. If possible please write an answer. Many thanks.

Per OP’s comment, the main question is showing, for $x^{\ast\ast} \in X^{\ast\ast}$ and $y^\ast \in Y^\ast$, we have $\|x^{\ast\ast} \otimes y^\ast\|_{K(X, Y)^\ast} = \|x^{\ast\ast}\|\|y^\ast\|$. Indeed, we first note that, for any $T \in K(X, Y)$,
$$|(x^{\ast\ast} \otimes y^\ast)(T)| = |x^{\ast\ast}(y^\ast \circ T)| \leq \|x^{\ast\ast}\|\|y^\ast \circ T\| \leq \|x^{\ast\ast}\|\|y^\ast\|\|T\|$$
So, $\|x^{\ast\ast} \otimes y^\ast\| \leq \|x^{\ast\ast}\|\|y^\ast\|$. Conversely, per definition of norms on dual spaces, for any $\epsilon > 0$, there exists $x^\ast \in S_{X^\ast}$ and $y \in S_Y$ s.t. $|x^{\ast\ast}(x^\ast)| \geq (1 - \epsilon)\|x^{\ast\ast}\|$ and $|y^\ast(y)| \geq (1 - \epsilon)\|y^\ast\|$. Now, $x^\ast \otimes y$ can be regarded as an element of $K(X, Y)$ as follows:
$$(x^\ast \otimes y)(x) = x^\ast(x)y, \forall x \in X$$
I claim that $x^\ast \otimes y$ has norm $1$. Indeed,
$$\|(x^\ast \otimes y)(x)\| = |x^\ast(x)|\|y\| \leq \|x^\ast\|\|y\|\|x\| = \|x\|$$
So, $\|x^\ast \otimes y\| \leq 1$. Conversely, for any $\delta> 0$, there exists $x \in S_X$ s.t. $|x^\ast(x)| \geq (1 - \delta)\|x^\ast\| = 1 - \delta$. Thus,
$$\|x^\ast \otimes y\| \geq \|(x^\ast \otimes y)(x)\| = |x^\ast(x)|\|y\| \geq 1 - \delta$$
Letting $\delta \to 0$ proves the claim.
Now, we note that,
$$[y^\ast \circ (x^\ast \otimes y)](x) = y^\ast(x^\ast(x)y) = y^\ast(y)x^\ast(x)$$
That is, $y^\ast \circ (x^\ast \otimes y) = y^\ast(y)x^\ast$. Thus,
$$\begin{split}
\|x^{\ast\ast} \otimes y^\ast\| &\geq |(x^{\ast\ast} \otimes y^\ast)(x^\ast \otimes y)|\\
&= |x^{\ast\ast}(y^\ast \circ (x^\ast \otimes y))|\\
&= |x^{\ast\ast}(y^\ast(y)x^\ast)|\\
&= |x^{\ast\ast}(x^\ast)||y^\ast(y)|\\
&\geq (1 - \epsilon)^2\|x^{\ast\ast}\|\|y^\ast\|
\end{split}$$
Letting $\epsilon \to 0$ finishes the proof.

Thank you very much for the solution. Learned few interesting things.

Is $K(X, Y)$ playing any special role here? I hope your proof will also occur in $L(X, Y)$. Am I right?

@Tuh You mean, if $x^{\ast\ast} \otimes y^\ast$ is regarded as an element of $L(X, Y)^\ast$ instead of $K(X, Y)^\ast$, does it still have norm $|x^{\ast\ast}||y^\ast|$? Yes, it does. You can just replace all $K(X, Y)$ by $L(X, Y)$ in the proof and everything still works.

Yes. Exactly I wanted to say this. Thank you once again.
